# Calculation of electron vertex correction in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I am trying two days now to simplify the numerator of the electron vertex correction in the one-loop contribution. My problem is to prove that
$$\bar{u}(p')\left[-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu l^2+(-y \gamma ^{\nu} q_{\nu}+z\gamma ^{\nu} p_{\nu})\gamma^{\mu}((1-y) \gamma ^{\nu} q_{\nu}+z\gamma ^{\nu} p_{\nu})+m^2\gamma^{\mu}-2m((1-2y)q^\mu +2zp^\mu)\right]u(p)$$

$$=\bar{u}(p')\left[\gamma^\mu\left(-\frac{1}{2} l^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right) +(p'^\mu+p^\mu)mz(z-1)+q^{\mu}m(z-2)(x-y)\right]u(p)$$

where $q=k'-k=p'-p$, $ x+y+z=1$ $(x,y,z$ are the feynmann parameters$)$,$l=k+yq-zp$, $\bar{u}(p')$ and $u(p)$ are dirac spinors with amd $m$ is the electron mass.

My calculations made me half way. I am curently here

$$=\bar{u}(p')\left[\gamma^\mu\left(-\frac{1}{2} l^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right)+2m^2z\gamma^\mu+2p^\mu m z(z-2)-q^\mu m(2y(z-2)+2))\right]u(p)$$

As you can see i am very close but i can't go all the way. Can anyone help me with this proof?

(It's in the page 191 and 192 in Peskin and Schroeder "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory")

Comment: Seems to me like u have a mistake in your calculation. You still have a free $\gamma^\mu$-term $2m^2 z \gamma^\mu$ which can not contract with anything and should not appear in the final answer.

Comment: I had to add and subtract this term in order to make the first half right. Now i am stuck with this and the other and i dont know how to go all the way.
The calculations up to this point are correct. I checked them 10 times since yesterday.

Comment: How did you get rid of the mixing terms ${\gamma^\mu} {\not p} {\not q} m^2$  which appear in the first large parenthesis?

Comment: I used the identity ${\not a} {\not b}=2a\cdot  b - {\not b} {\not a}$

Comment: Is something known about the scalar products $a\cdot b$ for $a\neq b$?

Comment: Yes, its the momentum of the particles, I put the relations above

Comment: I still think there should not appear the $\gamma^\mu$ term uncontracted like in your case.

Comment: I solved it. Yes it has to be there, because $\gamma^\mu m$ can be written as  $\gamma^\mu \not p = 2p^\mu- \not p\gamma^\mu$ and $\not p=p'-q$ and we get the cancelation we want after a lot of calulation

Comment: And there I was thinking you know nothing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I cannot tell you where your calculation went wrong, but Peskin and Schroeder are correct. Here is a step-by-step derivation. Forgive me for not including any English, the steps should be self-evident (but see the bottom).

We start with
$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\ell^2+(-yq\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/)\gamma^\mu\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+m^2\gamma^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p).$$

Then, the tedium begins:

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\ell^2-q\!\!\!/\gamma^\mu y\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+p\!\!\!/\gamma^\mu z\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+m^2\gamma^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu\ell^2-(2q^\mu-\gamma^\mu q\!\!\!/)y\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+(2p^\mu-\gamma^\mu p\!\!\!/)z\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+m^2\gamma^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+q\!\!\!/y\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]-p\!\!\!/z\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+m^2\right]-2q^\mu y\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]+2p^\mu z\left[(1-y)q\!\!\!/+zp\!\!\!/\right]-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+yz(q\!\!\!/p\!\!\!/+p\!\!\!/q\!\!\!/)-zp\!\!\!/q\!\!\!/-z^2m^2+m^2\right]-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu -2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2yzp\cdot q-z(2p\cdot q-q\!\!\!/p\!\!\!/)-z^2m^2+m^2\right]-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2(y-1)zp\cdot q+z(p\!\!\!/+q\!\!\!/)p\!\!\!/-zp\!\!\!/p\!\!\!/-z^2m^2+m^2\right]-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2(y-1)zp\cdot q+zp\!\!\!/'p\!\!\!/+(1-z-z^2)m^2\right]-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2(y-1)zp\cdot q+(1-z-z^2)m^2\right]+z\gamma^\mu p\!\!\!/'p\!\!\!/-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2(y-1)zp\cdot q+(1-z-z^2)m^2\right]+z(2p'^\mu-p\!\!\!/'\gamma^\mu)m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+y(1-y)q^2+2(y-1)zp\cdot q+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+z(y-1)(q^2+2p\cdot q)+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+z(y-1)(p'^2-p^2)+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+z(y-1)(p\!\!\!/'^2-p\!\!\!/^2)+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2-z(y-1)m^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+z(y-1)\gamma^\mu p\!\!\!/'^2+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2-z(y-1)m^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+z(y-1)(2p'^\mu-p\!\!\!/'\gamma^\mu)p\!\!\!/'+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2-z(y-1)m^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+z(y-1)(2p'^\mu-m\gamma^\mu)p\!\!\!/'+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2-z(y-1)m^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2z(y-1)mp'^\mu-z(y-1)m\gamma^\mu p\!\!\!/'+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2-z(y-1)m^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2z(y-1)mp'^\mu-z(y-1)m(2p'^\mu-m\gamma^\mu)+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+2zp'^\mu m-2myz q^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu-2m\left[(1-2y)q^\mu+2zp^\mu\right]\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]-2m z      p^\mu+2mz^2p^\mu+2m z      q^\mu-2myz q^\mu-2m(1-2y)  q^\mu\right\}u(p),$$

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+mz(z-1)(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+m( z-z^2+2z-2yz-2+4y)q^\mu\right\}u(p).$$

Finally, after rearranging the last term, we get the desired result:

$$\bar{u}(p')\left\{\gamma^\mu\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ell^2+(1-x)(1-y)q^2+(1-2z-z^2)m^2\right]+mz(z-1)(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+m(z-2)(x-y)q^\mu\right\}u(p).$$

For this derivation, I used the following identities:

\begin{align*}
x+y+z&=1,\\
p'&=p+q,\\
p\!\!\!/\gamma^\mu&=2p^\mu-\gamma^\mu p\!\!\!/,\\
q\!\!\!/\gamma^\mu&=2q^\mu-\gamma^\mu q\!\!\!/,\\
p\!\!\!/q\!\!\!/&=2p\cdot q-q\!\!\!/p\!\!\!/,\\
p\!\!\!/u(p)&=m~u(p),\\
\bar{u}(p')p\!\!\!/'&=\bar{u}(p')m,\\
\bar{u}(p')q\!\!\!/u(p)&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: There're some steps that can use $p^2=m^2$ directly, why not?

Comment: It is eminently possible that I missed some possible simplifications. My goal was simply to verify the P&S result.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my idea:

1. at first, only $(-y{\not q}+z{\not p}) \gamma^\mu ((1-y) {\not q}+z{\not p})$ need special concern. We rewrite terms before $\gamma^\mu$ in ${\not p'}$ and ${\not q}$ using $p=p'-q $ while kept terms after $\gamma^\mu$ unchanged, we use ${\not p}u(p)=mu(p)$ and $\overline{u}(p'){\not p'}=\overline{u}(p')m$, only terms involves ${\not q}$ and $\gamma^\mu$ remains. With $\overline{u}(p')$ and $u(p)$ implicit,

$(-y{\not q}+z{\not p}) \gamma^\mu ((1-y) {\not q}+z{\not p})$

$=(z{\not p'}-(y+z){\not q}) \gamma^\mu ((1-y) {\not q}+z{\not p})$

$=(mz-(y+z){\not q}) \gamma^\mu ((1-y) {\not q}+mz)$

$=\underline{m^2 z^2\gamma^\mu} + mz(1-y)\gamma^\mu{\not q} -mz(y+z){\not q}\gamma^\mu -(y+z)(1-y){\not q}\gamma^\mu{\not q}$

2a. First term is fine, we swap the last term, as it gives $\gamma^\mu q^2$, remember $\overline{u}(p')q^\mu{\not q}u(p)=\overline{u}(p')q^\mu({\not p'}-{\not p})u(p)=\overline{u}(p')({\not p'}q^\mu-q^\mu{\not p})u(p)=\overline{u}(p')(mq^\mu-q^\mu m)u(p)=0$

$-(y+z)(1-y){\not q}\gamma^\mu{\not q}$

$=-(y+z)(1-y)(2q^\mu-\gamma^\mu{\not q}){\not q}$

$=-2(y+z)(1-y)q^\mu{\not q} + (y+z)(1-y)\gamma^\mu q^2$

$=\underline{(y+z)(1-y)\gamma^\mu q^2}$

2b. swap $\gamma^\mu {\not q}$ gives terms like ${\not q}\gamma^\mu$ which is no good, rewrite back to $p'-p$ then swap gives terms of $m\gamma^\mu$, $p^\mu$ and $p'^\mu$. Remember, only ${\not p'}$ before $\gamma^\mu$ and ${\not p}$ after $\gamma^\mu$ can contract with their corresponding $u$ to give $m$, $\gamma^\mu {\not p'}$ cannot contract with $\overline{u}(p')$ as there is a $\gamma^\mu$ between them.

$mz(1-y)\gamma^\mu{\not q}$

$=mz(1-y)[\gamma^\mu({\not p'}-{\not p})]$

$=mz(1-y)[\gamma^\mu{\not p'}-\gamma^\mu m]$

$=mz(1-y)[2p'^\mu -{\not p'}\gamma^\mu - m\gamma^\mu]$

$=mz(1-y)[2p'^\mu -m\gamma^\mu - m\gamma^\mu]$

$=\underline{-2m^2z(1-y)\gamma^\mu+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu}$

Similarly,

$-mz(y+z){\not q}\gamma^\mu$

$=-mz(y+z)[({\not p'}-{\not p})\gamma^\mu]$

$=-mz(y+z)[m\gamma^\mu-{\not p}\gamma^\mu]$

$=-mz(y+z)[m\gamma^\mu-2p^\mu+\gamma^\mu{\not p}]$

$=-mz(y+z)[m\gamma^\mu-2p^\mu+\gamma^\mu m]$

$=\underline{-2m^2z(y+z)\gamma^\mu + 2mz(y+z)p^\mu}$

Up to here, we actually get everything, the rest is simple algebra grouping terms.

3. Put everything into numerator, with $u(p)$, $\overline{u}'(p')$ implicit. Remember $x+y+z=1$

numerator

$=-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu l^2$
$+(m^2 z^2\gamma^\mu + (y+z)(1-y)\gamma^\mu q^2 -2m^2z(1-y)\gamma^\mu+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu -2m^2z(y+z)\gamma^\mu + 2mz(y+z)p^\mu)$
$+m^2 \gamma^\mu -2m((1-2y)q^\mu + 2zp^\mu) $

$=\gamma^\mu(-\frac{1}{2} l^2 +(1-x)(1-y) q^2 + m^2 z^2-2m^2z(1-y) -2m^2z(y+z)+m^2)$
$+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu + (2mz(y+z)-4mz)p^\mu -2m(1-2y)q^\mu$

$=\gamma^\mu(-\frac{1}{2} l^2 +(1-x)(1-y) q^2 + m^2(z^2-2z+2zy-2zy-2z^2+1)$
$+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu + 2mz(y+z-2)p^\mu -2m(1-2y)q^\mu$

$=\gamma^\mu (-\frac{1}{2}l^2+ (1-x)(1-y) q^2 + (1-2z-z^2)m^2)$
$+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu - 2mz(1+x)p^\mu -2m(1-2y)q^\mu$

We got the $\gamma^\mu$ term, and

Observing $ap'^\mu+bp^\mu+cq^\mu=\frac{a+b}{2}(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+\frac{a-b}{2}(p'^\mu-p^\mu)+cq^\mu=\frac{a+b}{2}(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+(\frac{a-b}{2}+c)q^\mu$

We further get:

$+2mz(1-y)p'^\mu - 2mz(1+x)p^\mu -2m(1-2y)q^\mu$

$=\frac{1}{2}(2mz(1-y)-2mz(1+x))(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+(\frac{1}{2}(2mz(1-y)+2mz(1+x))-2m(1-2y))q^\mu$

$=mz(-x-y)(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+m(z(1-y)+z(1+x)-2(x-y+z))q^\mu$

$=mz(z-1)(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+m(z(x-y)+2z-2(x-y)-2z)q^\mu$

$=mz(z-1)(p'^\mu+p^\mu)+m(z-2)(x-y)q^\mu$

and we get everything